# How to *keep track* of object count in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'd like to *keep track* of the number of specific managed objects. The same way `NSFetchedResultsController` does except that I do not need any data back, I just need a number. What's the most efficient way to do this?

As a side note, apparently I don't want to use `NSFetchedResultsController` in the most straightforward way because it would create bunch of faults and clog memory for no reason.

I was trying to achieve this by marrying `NSCountResultType` and `NSFetchedResultsController` but I get some weird crash when merging contexts:

```
NSError *error;
auto defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
auto fetchRequest = [NotificationModel MR_requestAllWhere:NotificationModelAttributes.isRead isEqualTo:@NO];

fetchRequest.includesSubentities = NO;
fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = NO;
fetchRequest.resultType = NSCountResultType;
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[];
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[];

self.notificationCountFetchController = [NotificationModel MR_fetchController:fetchRequest delegate:self useFileCache:NO groupedBy:nil inContext:defaultContext];
[self.notificationCountFetchController performFetch:&error];
[MagicalRecord handleErrors:error];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All changes in MagicalRecord go through root context so I register for `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` observation and fetch objects count on each save. Easy.

Answer (score 0):

[`- countForFetchRequest:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/countForFetchRequest:error:) should suffice your needs

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSUInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty obvious one, but it's not *tracking* it is a simple fetch. NSFetchedResultsController keeps track of objects and sends updates to delegate.

Comment: Yes it's fetch, what problems are you getting when doing this approach?

Comment: "Keep track" means to continuously receive updates when object count changes over time. What you suggest is a single fetch request.

Comment: Okay, you need kind of notification whenever there is a change in count. Seems like you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It’s really easy to get the number of results for a request with Core Data. When you only need the objects count it’s better to not fetch all the managed objects but just get the count. This is really easy with Core Data, instead of calling executeFetchRequest you have to call countForFetchRequest on your managedObjectContext.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
NSError *error = nil;
return [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

you can check also this answer at this [link](http://glenngeenen.be/ios-core-data-get-object-count/)

Comment: "Keep track" means to continuously receive updates when object count changes over time. What you suggest is a single fetch request.